# vueuse useInfiniteScroll issue with nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, vueuse

i am trying to use infinite scroll functionality using vueuse
i am using nuxt 3 so there might be some issue with nuxt3

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useInfiniteScroll } from '@vueuse/core'

const el = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const data = ref([1])

useInfiniteScroll(
  el,
  () => {
    const length = data.value.length + 1
    data.value.push(...Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => length + i))
  },
  { distance: 10 },
)
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="el" class="flex flex-col gap-2 p-4 w-300px h-100 m-auto overflow-auto bg-gray-500/5 rounded">
    <div v-for="item in data" :key="item" class="h-15 bg-gray-500/5 rounded p-3">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

without even scrolling it is loading function, i have tried using

```
import { vInfiniteScroll } from '@vueuse/components'
```

declarative way as well but this is not working for me , any work around for this ?

Comment: If your initial data are larger than scroll container, then it wont start loading until you scroll down.